# Animating HTML “Ranking” Tables with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, visual-studio, html-table

I want to create the animating HTML ranking table with the jQuery plugin found here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/01/animating-html-ranking-tables-with-javascript/

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I've created a new C# website, saved the following jQuery files in "Scripts/":

- animator.js
- jquery-1.4.3.js
- rankingTableUpdate.js

My Style sheet is located here:"App_Themes/Main Theme/Styles/Site.css"

I'm using a masterpage which is Site.master. I have pasted the following code into "Default.aspx":

```
    <br />
      <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="40%">
        <tr>
        <th>Researcher</th>
        <th>Close Ratio</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><strong>John</strong> Doe</td>
          <td><strong>1</strong> in <strong>25</strong> CONV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><strong>John</strong> Zert</td>
          <td><strong>1</strong> in <strong>51</strong> CONV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><strong>Johnny</strong> Halliday</td>
          <td><strong>1</strong> in <strong>37</strong> CONV</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><strong>Johnathan</strong> Bell</td>
          <td><strong>1</strong> in <strong>31</strong> CONV</td>
          </table>
```

I'm wanting to find out how do I connect this table to the JavaScript and get it running.

Do I need to reference "updating" and "constant" columns in the above table? If yes, where can I find the resource to do it?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some documentation on how to use the plugin on the [usage](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/01/animating-html-ranking-tables-with-javascript/#usage) section of that page.

Looking at your code, it seems that there are a couple of issues with you're html.. the plugin requires that you have a table with an explicit `thead` defined, this is where you `th` elements should go.  There's an example of the expected table structure in the usage section.

Also, the plugin works by taking two table elements, then making one animate to the other - currently you only have a single table, so there's nothing to animate.  If you want to use it to show the animation of a table sort, then check out the [code for the financial example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/financialExample.js) from the page.  This works by creating a new copy of the table which has it's rows in the sorted order when the user clicks on the column header, then animating the current table to this new one.

*By the way, I'm the author of this plugin and I'm not actually maintaining the code, so if it doesn't work due to browser changes then I'm afraid you might need to fix it yourself, or find someone else to!*

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate your help. You have developed a great plugin! All the best!

Comment: Mark if you do not mind i have a question regarding your plugin, im taking data live through a php script. For now i call the rankingTableUpdate inside the success of AJAX, updates fine every say 10s (both removes and add rows according to DB). I'm curious as of when should the sorting take place in order for the animation to work. If you have the time i'd appreciate it if you could explaine me. Thank you

Comment: Sorting is essentially the same as updating via AJAX - you just replacing the old table for a new one (which is sorted in a different order).  The first thing is to create a table which is sorted in a the order you want (which can be done client or server side, depending on how it needs to work), then call the update function passing it in.